# Airflow DAG Runs Daily Excluding Weekends?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is it possible to create an Airflow DAG that runs every day except for Saturday and Sunday? It doesn't seem like this is possible since you only have a **start_date** and a **schedule_interval**.

I'm setting up a workflow that will process a batch of files every morning. The files won't be present on weekends though only Monday through Friday. I could simply use a timeout setting of 24 hours which essentially makes Saturday and Sunday timeout because the file would never appear on those days but this would mark the DAG as failed for those two days and that would be very pleasant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`'schedule_interval': '0 0 * * 1-5'` runs at 00:00 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.

Comment: It should do the trick! It works for us currently. Let me know if you have any issues, and I'll try to assist.

Answer (score 5):

The answer from Zack already has a weekdays cron schedule that'll do what you want (`0 0 * * 1-5`), but I wanted to add an answer with a site for examples of common cron schedules, ahem, *crontab expressions*.

I use this with Airflow a lot to come up with a DAG's `schedule_interval`.

The main app to help you design a cron schedule interactively is at [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/).

An example only on weekdays schedule - https://crontab.guru/every-weekday

More common examples (e.g., every half hour, every quarter, etc) - https://crontab.guru/examples.html

Comment: Thank you for expanding on my answer Taylor! Very helpful examples.

Comment: Okay I'll be even more impressed with crontab.guru if they can do every weekday excluding New York Stock Exchange holidays! XD

Comment: It looks like cron doesn't really support excluding specific dates (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128628/169772), but you could do the exclusion part in your code and keep the NYSE holidays in an Airflow Variable.  Perhaps a BranchOperator for whether it's an NYSE holiday?  I'd be curious to know what you come up with here too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need and ended up putting this at the beginning of my dags -- it's similar to the ShortCircuitOperator.

```py
import logging
from airflow.models import SkipMixin, BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults


class pull_file_decision_operator(BaseOperator, SkipMixin):

   template_fields = ('execution_date',)

   @apply_defaults
   def __init__(self,
                day_of_week, 
                hour_of_day,
                execution_date,
                **kwargs):

       self.day_of_week = day_of_week
       self.hour_of_week = hour_of_day
       self.execution_date = execution_date

   def execute(self, context):
       # https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday

       run_dt = self.execution_date
       dow = self.day_of_week
       hod = self.hour_of_day

       if run_dt.weekday() == dow and run_dt.hour == hod:
          return True
       else:
          downstream_tasks = context['task'].get_flat_relatives(upstream=False)
          logging.info('Skipping downstream tasks...')
          logging.info("Downstream task_ids %s", downstream_tasks)

          if downstream_tasks:
             self.skip(context['dag_run'],
                       context['ti'].execution_date,
                       downstream_tasks)
```

Comment: Sorry could you please explain the code a little and/or give an example of how to use the operator (my brain must be in weekend mode already because it's glazing over :D)

Comment: Basically you could put this in front of your dag to evaluate whether the time/date is appropriate to kick off downstream tasks (in this case it just looks at the day of the week and marks itself as successful if the execution_date is a weekday and the hour matches -- although if you only care about weekdays and not hour you could remove that second part.)

If it doesn't match (i.e. if it's a day on the weekend), it will skip all downstream tasks. The dag run would then be marked as successful.